# Get indexpath of a row in table with multiple sections

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Im currently implementing expandable uitableviewcell in my project. [This is my reference tutorial](https://medium.com/@lawgimenez/implementing-the-expandable-cell-in-ios-uitableview-7288bcbb7587).

My viewcontroller has 4 sections and the 4th section (with 1 row) is the only one that needs to be opened/closed. I cannot get the indexpath of this section.

The code doesn't work because xcode seems to be confused as to what section and row am I referring to.

Here's the code (it's just the same as in the tutorial)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 2{
        if dataCellExpanded {
            print("111")
            dataCellExpanded = false
        } else {
            dataCellExpanded = true
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        if dataCellExpanded {
            return 250
        }else {
            return 50
        }
    }
        return 50
}
```

Comment: `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)`, probably the index-path for your 4th section's 1st row; you need _both_ components of the index-path to address that particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 1 row then should you not check `indexPath.row == 0` instead of `indexPath.row == 2` if you dont have expanding rows in other section. And if you have you can check `indexPath.section` for the section tapped.